# how to Save data in multiple tables for same user in CakePHP 2.6

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, cakephp

who to save data in multiple table for same user table has hasMany relation
 if i change $this->CompanyContact->saveAll($this->request->data) CompanyContact to User then only user data save if i change CompanyContact to CompanyAddress then only Address save

```
this my contoller function 

public function editcompanyprofile($id = null) {
    $this->layout = 'main';

    if ($this->request->is(array('put', 'post'))) {

        $this->request->data['CompanyAddress'] = $this->request->data['Company']['CompanyAddress'];
        unset($this->request->data['Company']['CompanyAddress']);

        if ($this->request->data['CompanyProfile']['profile_img']['name'] != "") {
            $sFileName = time() . "_" . str_replace(" ", "_", $this->request->data['CompanyProfile']['profile_img']['name']);
            $sPath = "profile";
            $file = $this->Pk->uploadImage($this->request->data['CompanyProfile']['profile_img'], $sFileName, $sPath);

            if ($file['status'] == 'success') {
                unset($this->request->data['CompanyProfile']['profile_img']);
                $this->request->data['CompanyProfile']['profile_img'] = $file['url'];
            } else {
                $this->request->data['CompanyProfile']['profile_img'] = "";
            }
        } else {
            unset($this->request->data['CompanyProfile']['profile_img']);
        }
        if ($this->CompanyContact->saveAll($this->request->data)) {

            return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'companyprofile', $id));
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    } else {

        $options = array('conditions' => array('CompanyContact.company_id'), 'recursive' => 2);
        $this->request->data = $this->CompanyContact->find('first', $options);
          $this->set('options', $options);
      //  print_r($this->request->data);exit;
    }
}





<?php echo $this->Form->create('CompanyProfile', array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('User.id'); ?>


            <lable id="view-edit-lable">First Name</lable>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('User.fname', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter First Name Here..', 'label' => false, 'required')); ?>
            <br>
            <lable id="view-edit-lable">Last Name</lable>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('User.lname', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter First Name Here..', 'label' => false, 'required')); ?>  
            <br>
            <lable id="view-edit-lable">Company Name</lable>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('Company.company_name', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter First Name Here..', 'label' => false, 'required')); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('Company.id', array('type' => 'hidden')); ?>
            <br>

            <lable id="view-edit-lable">Website Url</lable>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Last_name" placeholder="Website" >
            <br>
            <lable id="view-edit-lable">Email Address</lable>    
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('User.email', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter Last Name Here..', 'label' => false, 'required')); ?>

            <br>
            <lable id="view-edit-lable">Contact no</lable>
            <div class="phone-list">
                <div class="input-group phone-input" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">

                        <button type="submit" style="height:45px;font-size: 15px;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"></span></button>
                    </span>
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('User.mobile_number', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '+1 (999) 999 9999', 'label' => false)); ?>

                </div>

            </div>
            <br>

            <lable id="view-edit-lable">Address</lable>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('Company.CompanyAddress.address1', array('class' => 'form-control', 'label' => false)); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('Company.CompanyAddress.id', array('type' => 'hidden')); ?>
            <br>
            <lable id="view-edit-lable">Address 2</lable>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('Company.CompanyAddress.address2', array('class' => 'form-control', 'label' => false, 'placeholder' => 'Floor #')); ?>
            <br>

            <lable id="view-edit-lable">City</lable>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('Company.CompanyAddress.city', array('class' => 'form-control', 'label' => false)); ?>
            <br>
            <lable id="view-edit-lable">State</lable>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('Company.CompanyAddress.state', array('type' => 'select', 'options' => array('New York' => 'New York', 'Connecticut' => 'Connecticut', 'New Jersey' => 'New Jersey'), 'selected' => 'New York', 'label' => false, 'empty' => 'Select State', 'style' => 'width:100%;',
                'class' => 'btn dropdown-toggle selectpicker btn-default'));
            ?>
            <br>
            <lable id="view-edit-lable">Zip Code</lable> 
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Company.CompanyAddress.zipcode', array('type' => 'number', 'class' => 'form-control', 'label' => false)); ?>
                <br> 
                <lable id="view-edit-lable">Country</lable>
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('Company.CompanyAddress.country', array('type' => 'select', 'options' => array('USA' => 'USA'), 'selected' => 'USA', 'label' => false, 'empty' => 'Select State', 'style' => 'width:100%;',
                    'class' => 'btn dropdown-toggle selectpicker btn-default'));
                ?>


<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try replace this code

```
if ($this->CompanyContact->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
```

to this:

```
if ($this->CompanyContact->saveAll($this->request->data) && $this->CompanyAddress->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
```

Comment: its working but i also have to store data in one more table CompanyProfile

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below Its not your solution because your code is messed up so crate array for particular model and then save it. also don't forget to import model.

```
  $addrs = $this->request->data['Company']['CompanyAddress']; 
  $data = array('id' => 1, 'address' => $addrs);
  $this->CompanyAddress->save($data)
```